# when i try to run sudo apt-get update,I got this much errors,

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

```
<pre>
Err:17 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu impish/mongodb-org/3.0 Release
404  Not Found [IP: 2600:9000:2242:2200:1e:e933:9800:93a1 80]
Get:18 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release [3,457 B]
Get:19 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release.gpg [801 B]
Ign:19 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file &apos;main/binary-i386/Packages&apos; as 
repository &apos;https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease&apos; 
doesn&apos;t support architecture &apos;i386&apos;
W: GPG error: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 Release: The 
following signatures couldn&apos;t be verified because the public key is not 
available: NO_PUBKEY 656408E390CFB1F5
E: The repository &apos;https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 
Release&apos; is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can&apos;t be done securely, and is therefore 
disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository &apos;http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu impish/mongodb-org/3.0 
Release&apos; does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can&apos;t be done securely, and is therefore 
disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release: The 
following signatures couldn&apos;t be verified because the public key is not 
available: NO_PUBKEY BC711F9BA15703C6
E: The repository &apos;http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 
Release&apos; is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can&apos;t be done securely, and is therefore 
disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
</pre>
```

When i try to run sudo apt-get update i got this much errors,I am running pop os in my pc,Anyone know how to solve this? if so please help me!

Comment: Your `sources.list` is misconfigured, you have mixed  `xenial` , `focal` and `bionic` .

Comment: When i reinstall mongodb and done source file configuration right,all of error gone but expect .N: Skipping acquire of configured file &apos;main/binary-i386/Packages&apos; as 
repository &apos;https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease&apos; 
doesn&apos;t support architecture &apos;i386&apos;

Answer (score 0):

If you not interested in mongo db remove mongo db repositories from sources.list but if you are trying to install mongo dB try the following method

Unsigned repository is caused due to not adding mongo Db public key for its repository

`wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -`
run the command for your required mongo Db version

the above mention command is for mongodB version 5

If you want to install mongo db version 3 follow this documentation
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Nothing was changed broo

Comment: Can you please elaborate what did you do and what you are trying to do and can I get your pop os version?

Comment: I try to do sudo apt-get update after running wget command then i got this errors idk what happened ,I am running pop os 21.10.

Comment: Now this is the error:- N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: GPG error: http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FEB6023DC27AA466
E: The repository 'http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.